# Android fails to subscribe to multiple characteristics within service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to subscribe to multiple characteristics within the service and obtain notifications for both of the characteristics.

Here is my version with 1 char:

```
 @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = gatt.getServices().get(2).getCharacteristics();

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = characteristics.get(0);
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);


        }




        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(characteristicIDs[0])) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Char for Beacons");
                int threshValue = characteristic.getValue()[0];
                sendBeaconToCloud(threshValue);
            } else if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(characteristicIDs[1])) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Char for Sensors");
                convertSensorValues(characteristic.getValue());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(BluetoothConnActivity.this,"Unknown char", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

So then I decided to copy the block of code within onServicesDiscovered and also

```
characterics.get(1)
```

This didn't work, so I followed the method specified in here:
[How to subscribe to multiple BluetoothLE Characteristics with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230684/how-to-subscribe-to-multiple-bluetoothle-characteristics-with-android)

So this is the produced code:

```
public List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars;
 public BluetoothGatt myGatt;

 @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            chars = gatt.getServices().get(2).getCharacteristics();
            this.myGatt = gatt;
            subscribeToMultiple();

        }

        private void subscribeToMultiple() {
            if (chars.size() == 0) return;

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = chars.get(0);
            myGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            myGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }

        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt,descriptor,status);
            chars.remove(0);
            subscribeToMultiple();
        }
```

However, I just get output:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000a001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000a002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
```

but **onCharacteristicChanged** is never called.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First you can set for 0.When you receive onCharacteristicChanged for characteristics 0 then unsubscribe from it and enable for the characteristic 1.when you receive for 1 unsubscribe for 1 and re enable 0. It worked for me once.

Comment: Would prefer a solution that does not force me to do this, in addition Characteristic 2 sends at regular intervals, while the first one sends only once it detects a beacon, why occurs less frequently.